# Generalized Linear Mixed Model or Linear Mixed Effects Model?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

I am trying to use a time field (number of minutes ex. 60, 120, 240, ect) as a response variable in a GLMM to see if this data predicts the fixed variables of distance and duration. I am trying to ask if an animal travels further when they are spending more time in a certain environment. I thought that a GLMM would be appropriate but should I be using a LMER instead? I am having individual animal as a random effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed a Poisson regression seems to be more suitable framework for your problem than a simple LMER

Comment: So set a GLMM with poisson as the family? Instead of running an LMER?

Comment: Yes... As your dependent variable seems to be some counting variable and not continuous one

Comment: Yes, my dependent is the time (in minutes) that the animal spent feeding. So would my code be glmer(minutes~distance+time +1|ID, family=poisson)...?

Comment: V.Vancak why not use an lmer? I'm getting quite confused as to why I should be using the GLMM, mainly because R is not happy with my code.

Comment: 1. You are probably missing brackets, namely, minutes ~ distance+time +(1|ID), family=poisson). 2. Lmer assumes continuous $y$, in your story $y$ is has integer values, thus Poisson may fit better. Anyway, you should be guided by theory rather by guessing, And you can compare the both models w.r.t. some criteria